# Need help setting up class property value in another TS file

Tags: javascript, typescript

Value assigned to class property in first TS file is not traveling to other TS files

first.ts

```
export class first{
public name:any;
function getName{
    console.log("Name is: "+this.name);
  }
}
```

Second.ts

```
import {first} from ./first

let fs = new first;
fs.name = “Mohit”;
fs.getName();
```

I am expecting name property to keep the value carry to other TS files.
However, in console I am getting "Name is: undefined"

Comment: You have a bunch of syntax errors in your code. It's not possible to answer your question until you fix them.